# Delete Blob file from the Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I am new to the Azure DatabaseDB, I want to check the files uploaded to the blob storage, and to delete one by one from portal.azure.com.

Is it possible to see the list and delete it from portal.azure.com?

> Note: I just want to delete the files stored in the blob storage, not
>   the blob storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solutions.

Click on your `Storage Account` -> Click on `Containers` => Select `Container` => Click on `File` => And finally `Delete`

=============================================

**UPDATE:**

[Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/features/storage-explorer/) also provides the same features. Free tool to easily manage your Azure cloud storage resources anywhere, from Windows, macOS, or Linux

Upload, download, and manage Azure blobs, files, queues and tables, as well as Azure Cosmos DB and Azure Data Lake Storage entities. Easily access virtual machine disks and work with either Azure Resource Manager or classic storage accounts. Manage and configure cross-origin resource sharing rules.

Thank You.

Comment: I can only mark it after 2 days. but you can `upvote it` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from your C# code also-

```
private CloudBlobContainer blobContainer;

public void DeleteFile(string uniqueFileIdentifier)
{
  this.AssertBlobContainer();

  var blob = this.blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
  blob.DeleteIfExists();
}

private void AssertBlobContainer()
{
// only do once
if (this.blobContainer == null)
{
    lock (this.blobContainerLockObj)
    {
        if (this.blobContainer == null)
        {
            var client = this.cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            this.blobContainer = client.GetContainerReference(this.containerName.ToLowerInvariant());

            if (!this.blobContainer.Exists())
            {
                throw new CustomRuntimeException("Container {0} does not exist in azure account", containerName);
            }
        }
    }
}

if (this.blobContainer == null) throw new NullReferenceException("Blob Empty");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to delete it from portal.azure.com, now I have found the solution.

Comment: @VIVEK - the OP already explained it to you - they wanted a portal solution, not a code solution. And you also made the assumption they're working with c#. That's probably why you got a downvote.

Comment: @VIVEK A down vote? Here's a free up vote. I was looking for a C# solution and stumble this useful piece of code. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: What is blobContainerLockObj? I cant get this work. Anyone can get this work?